# How do I remove '##' symbol that appears in Rmarkdown while printing console output?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there any nicer way to display console output without '##' symbol in pdf generated by Rmarkdown

I have tried searching around here and googling for a solution, but I haven't found anything that solves my problem.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a code chunk at the top of your document, you can write e.g.

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = "")
```

The default is `comment = "##"`.

Comment: Is there any more nicer way to display console output in pdf generated by rmarkdown?

Comment: Even if I set this in code chunk at top of the document it shows "$" symbol if I do `str(df)` in another code chunk

Answer (score 1):

Use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA)` or `{r chunk1, comment = NA}` in the chunk options if you don't want to set it globally